# Configuring NGINX to work with memcache for reverse_proxy_cache

Tags: nginx, memcache

Is there any way to configure nginx to use memcache for storing cache data, as opposed to using files stored on hard drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Nginx [HttpMemcachedModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule) allows the use of Memcached as storage, but does not store HTTP headers with data - all pages served via Memcached storage have the default `Content-Type` and do not honor `Last-Modified`/`If-Modified-Since` headers and proper `304 Not Modified` header.

The [Enhanced Nginx Memached Module](http://blog.octo.com/en/http-caching-with-nginx-and-memcached/) is based on the standard module and has additional features which include storing HTTP headers together with data honoring the required HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably with [HttpMemcachedModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMemcachedModule).

Also, consider the StackOverflow thread title "[How to configure NGINX with Memcache to serve HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150995/how-to-configure-nginx-with-memcache-to-serve-html)"

[400% improvement](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/)? Yes please.